# What does the GitHub contact gold star mean?

Tags: github

On the [GitHub contact page](https://github.com/contact), I see the following message:

> If you use 140 characters or fewer, we'll give you a gold star.

I sent a message that contained 139 characters and I got a gold star.

> [image]

What does this mean? Is it just for fun or does it have any usage?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just for fun. It's much the same as if you vote my answer up 100 times and I get a badge. If you could do that, I'll let you know if that or the gold star gives more virtual satisfaction.

The advantage is more for GitHub, it's a very clever way of reducing support requests down to the absolute minimum text. If the same were applied to answers on this site, I'd not have added the attempt at humour which adds nothing to my answer.

Comment: Your answer is correct. Github support told me the same: *It's just a way of saying that we appreciate short and to-the-point feedback, rather than long and unclear elaborations.* and *the gold star is to invoke a feeling of zen-like happiness.* :-) Thanks! Github is great!